# How to get coordinates for the corner points on the visible Map display? (in new SwiftUI Map object)

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

What would be the code to get the co-ordinates (i.e. CLLocationCoordinate2D) for the corner points on a visible map display in SwiftUI?

NOTE this is using therefore the new Map/SwiftUI approach.

Assume that within SwiftUI I am in

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        MapReader { mapProxy in
            Map(position: $mapCamPos) {
               .
               .
               .
            }
            .onReceive(locationMgr.$location) { location in

                    // HOW TO DERIVE CO-ORDINATES AT THIS POINT???

                    mapCamPos =  .camera(MapCamera(
                        centerCoordinate: location.coordinate,
                        distance: distance,
                        heading: locationMgr.headingDegrees
                    ))
             }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Use the Span + center of the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should track the change of the map camera using [`onMapCameraChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map/4231686-onmapcamerachange), and an additional state:

```
Map {
    ...
}
.onMapCameraChange(frequency: .continuous /* or .onEnd depending on your needs */) { context in
    // currentMapRect is a @State that you should add to your view
    currentMapRect = context.rect
}
```

Then, in `onReceive` or wherever else, you can use the `minX`, `minY`, `maxX`, `maxY` properties of `currentMapRect` to find the four corners' coordinates. Note that you need to convert these x-y values to geographical coordinates e.g.

```
let bottomRightPoint = MKMapPoint(x: currentMapRect.maxX, y: currentMapRect.maxY)
let bottomRightCoordinate = bottomRightPoint.coordinate
```